# Dynamically convert timestamp to a different timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I am using moment.js and moment-timezone. how can I create a function to convert `2016-06-12 06:22:18` UTC time to the user's timezone time and then format the time to `Jun 12, 2015 6:22 PM`

---

for example:

```
updateTime("2016-06-12 06:22:18");
```

if in chicago, the output will be:

```
"Jun 12, 2016, 1:22 AM"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
moment.utc("2016-06-12 06:22:18", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss").tz('America/Chicago').format("MMM D, YYYY, hh:mm a")
```

Comment: Seemingly he wants the time to be localized for any user, so tz('America/Chicago') should be replaced with local()

Comment: What does the "a" at the end mean in `format("MMM D, YYYY, hh:mm a")`?

Comment: @akazemis local() does not work

Comment: also ,any way to write a function i can call each time?

Comment: 'a' is a marker for AM/PM.

Comment: @ShivV Okay, also can you update answer if function? is it possible to add: for seconds, show `a few seconds ago`. for minutes: `a few minutes ago` and `one hour ago`?

Comment: @johnjay22113 local() works, have a look into JSFiddle I've made : https://jsfiddle.net/1jm73out/

Comment: 'a' at the end is for am/pm by the way

Comment: @akazemis yes local() works but what does it do? what's the difference between local() and moment.tz.guess()?

Comment: @johnjay22113 if you're using moment.tz.guess() it's no different from local(), I said that regarding to Shiv V's code that says .tz('America/Chicago') which is kind of hard-coded

Comment: you can find the method I suggested in my answer

Comment: @akazemis, okay thanks!

Comment: They are quite different.  `local()` uses the browser's own time zone awareness built into the `Date` object.  `moment.tz.guess()` will try to guess the time zone, but could certainly guess incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The function you need would be like this :

```
function getLocalDate (input)
{
  var dt= moment.utc(input);
  dt.add(moment().utcOffset(),'minutes');
  return moment(dt).format('MMM D, YYYY, hh:mm a');
};
```

Or this :

```
function getLocalDate(input)
{
  return moment.utc(input).local().format('MMM D, YYYY, hh:mm a');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey this links may help you

https://gist.github.com/founddrama/2182389

https://www.sitepoint.com/managing-dates-times-using-moment-js/

http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/

Examples:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // June 20th 2016, 11:10:20 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Monday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Jun 20th 16
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2016 escaped 2016
moment().format();                       
moment.tz('2016-01-01', 'America/Chicago').format('z');
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at this answer, perhaps: [Get current timestamp from specific timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576786/get-current-timestamp-from-specific-timezone)

They solved by taking the time in UTC and converting it in the specific time

`var utcEpochSeconds = dateObj.getTime() + (dateObj.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);`